# exclude multiple groups TestNG

Tags: unit-testing, testing, automation, testng

```
public class c1 {

@Test(groups ={"first","third"})
public void p1_c1_1()
{
    System.out.println("p1_c1_1");

}
@Test(groups ="second")
public void p1_c1_2(){

    System.out.println("p1_c1_2");
}
@Test(groups ="third")
public void p1_c1_3(){

    System.out.println("p1_c1_3");
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite One" allow-return-values="true" verbose="1">
<test name="Test One">
    <groups>
        <define name="all">
            <include name="first" />
            <exclude name="second"/>
            <exclude name="third"/>
        </define>
        <run>
            <include name="all" />
        </run>
    </groups>
    <classes>
        <class name="c1" />
    </classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

if i run this testNg file I am getting p1_c1_1 printed which I must NOT because it is under both groups "first" and "second". so although p1_c1_1 is under included group called "first", it is still under excluded group called "third", so technically that method should not get executed. I want to know how to exclude a method which is under two groups with one of its groups included

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [dtd](http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd.php) specifies that    `<define>` just supports include as option

```
<!ELEMENT groups (define*,run?,dependencies?) >

<!ELEMENT define (include*)>
<!ATTLIST define
    name CDATA #REQUIRED>
```

So the only way you can achieve this is to run simple group instead of defining a group of groups.i.e.

```
<groups>
        <run>
             <include name="first" />
            <exclude name="second"/>
            <exclude name="third"/>
        </run>
    </groups>
```

and this would work the way you want.  Since there are no complex groupings atleast in this example, meta group is not even required in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to attempt at much more complex filtering in terms of Groups, perhaps you can try leveraging Beanshell capabilities within your TestNG suite XML file, wherein you have the luxury of defining whatever you want.

For more information around how to leverage Beanshell in TestNG suite xml file, you can take a look at [this](https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2013/08/21/beanshell-and-testng/) blog post of mine.